# Why can't Ruby's reduce method calculate from 2 to 4?

Tags: ruby

I want to perform a simple calculation of 2+3+4, so I wrote the following code. However, when I put the result of list, I only get "2 3 4". May I ask where did I have the problem?

```
list = [2, 3, 4]

list.reduce(0) {|start, i| start + i }

puts list
```

Comment: As a rule of thumb: an object cannot change its class, i.e. an array can never become an integer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

method `reduce` returns the result but you're not using it. `list` stays your list, `reduce` do not alter it

```
list = [2, 3, 4]
sum = list.reduce(0) { |start, i| start + i }
puts sum
```